# why is a server not sending size of file while trying to download that file

Tags: apache-2.2

My software is attempting to download a file from an apache server.

I noticed that the server is not sending the file size to the client to calculate the total time reamaining.

Why is the server not sending the file size to the client, as this is resulting in "unknown time remaining"?

Answer (score 1):

There is a header called `Content-Length` that your client software uses to determine the time remaining, but looking at the `Content-Length` header, subtracting the amount already downloaded, and then dividing the remaining amount by the current download speed and converting that into time.

If the server is not sending the `Content-Length` header, there is nothing you can do about it unless you have control over the server.

My guess is that the file is not being served by apache directly, but via something like PHP or CGI, and whoever wrote the script has forgotten (or not known about) adding that header to the output.